# How to test on Live paypal site with dummy credit cards

Tags: paypal, credit-card, testing-strategies

Right now I am able to test credit card functionality on development server using test/dummy credit cards. But not able to test the same functionality on live server. Are there any dummy credit cards, with which we can test the same on live site?